# Bootstrap : Add a junction between div

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid, row

[image]I'm trying to add a junction (a line) between 2 divs in the middle.

```
<div class="row">                   
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div style="background-color:#f39a6f;width:100%;height:100px;">
    ....1
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
    <div style="background-color:#ffff00;width:100%;height:100px;">
    ....2
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to have the junction (a line) always be the center of a row via absolute/relative positioning, with lower `z-index` than what those color blocks have so that the line is hidden behind the blocks but shown between the blocks.

The tricky part is accurately calculate the position of the junction line, due to the fact that *bootstrap* rows have their own paddings. That's why it's better to use `SCSS` so that you can read *bootstrap* default values for row and column settings, and calculate the junction line based on those.

But for demo purpose, I will stick with `CSS` and "hardcode" the pre-configured values from *bootstrap*.

#### HTML Structure

```html
<div class="row junction-row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
        <div class="block bg-primary"></div>
    </div>
    </div class="col-6 col-sm-4 offset-sm-5">
        <div class="block bg-danger"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.junction-row {
    height: 6rem;
    position: relative;
}

.junction-row::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--danger);
    height: 5%;

    // Default bootstrap row's padding is 1rem.
    // Width = 100% - left padding of the row - right padding of the row
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);

    // Top = total height 100% - the height of the line, and then divide by 2
    // to have the line stay in the center of the row.
    top: calc((100% - 5%) / 2);

    // Left = starting after the row's left padding
    left: 1rem;
 
    // Any value here, but it needs to be lower than what .block has
    z-index: 1;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    height: 6rem;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/vknor3cz/32/

Comment: Perfect, the block height is not fixed so i will have to find a way to stay in the middle.And when it comes to mobile size, i have to keep a small width for the line in the middle...Your answer is 80% accepted. I know now it's possible, i will try to make it with js...

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code will solve your problem.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card bg-success">
            <div class="card-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card bg-danger">
                <div class="card-body"></div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you code. When it comes to mobile size it must stay floating (1,2,3) and line should be smaller about (30px max)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can have this and have your column sizes at 6 each.  I can think of 2 ways.  Make them 5 and use this. This comes from their documentation on the grid system.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
<div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-5">
        One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        One of two columns
    </div>
 </div>
```

Or if you don't mind that junction being static width then you could do this. Effectively making the junction width static and each side equal in the remaining width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" style="width:30px"></div>
    <div class="col">
        2 of 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate , your answer but it does not create 3 floating div ... I need responsive in this case ...I tried class="col-xs-5 col-md-5" for 1 and 2 but the middle is too large...